# Compare DateTime Lists c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a List in C#

```
List<Dates>
public class Dates
{
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

**In List:**

Start - End

1. 2014-03-17 09:00:00   -   2014-03-17 10:00:00
2. 2014-03-17 10:59:59   -   2014-03-17 11:44:59

I will like to found the nr2, i meen everyting except the startToCheck and endToCheck range.

For example:

```
startToCheck = 2014-03-17 11:00:00
endToCheck = 2014-03-17 12:00:00
```

Obviously, my startToCheck is in List nr2, but is not find it.

I tried

```
if (Start <= startToCheck && End >= endToCheck)
```

But is not working...
Any help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Since nr2 `.End` is greater than `endToCheck`, why do you say nr2 is the right answer? Are you just looking for any overlap?

Comment: Yes I do, i need to get all others

Comment: I'm confused... In your example your "endToCheck" is outside of both of those ranges so why do you want the second item returned? You haven't actually explained what your check should do, just given us one example and one example does not define a problem. Should it return any range that overlaps with your given range? Only Dates where the startToCheck is inside the range and the endToCheck is after? Something else? You need to define precisely what behaviour you want and then we can explain why your approach is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To find any members of the list that overlap the `startToCheck` to `endToCheck` ranges, it suffices to find any members that contain either one.

```
List<Dates> listOfDateRanges;

var ans = listOfDateRanges.Where(r => (r.Start <= startToCheck && startToCheck < r.End) ||
                                      (r.Start < endToCheck && endToCheck <= r.End) ||
                                      (startToCheck <= r.Start && r.End <= endToCheck));
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. You've missed out the case where `startToCheck` is before the range and `endToCheck` is after it. though I guess it depends whether you are looking for any intersection or only a partial intersection. Sadly the OP has given us no clues as to what they actually want... :(

Comment: I added the missing case.

Answer (score 1):

From your question (and the other answers not being what you want), I infer that you want all dates who have **any** overlap with the range you're looking for.

It's hard to include all cases in a simple logical statement. It is much easier if you invert it. In other words, let's look for dates that **do not** overlap, and then get the other ones.

How would we define a range that doesn't overlap. Well, it can be one of two things:

- It already ended before your search period even started. (happened too early)
- **OR** It only started after your search period already ended. (happened too late)

This covers all cases, **assuming that the startdate can never be bigger than the end date** (which you should already be checking!).
So now, we invert the logic:

- It ended **after** your search period had started (= did not happen too early)
- **AND** it started **before** your search period ended (= did not happen too late)

If it's not too early, and it's not too late, then it must be *just right*.

```
    public class Dates
    {
        public DateTime Start {get; set;}
        public DateTime End {get; set;}
    }

    public List<Dates> FindOverlappingDates(DateTime beginPeriod, DateTime endPeriod)
    {
        var dateList = //fill in the list

        var dateRangesThatOverlap = datelist.Where(date =>
                 date.End > beginPeriod
                  && date.Start < endPeriod)

        return dateRangesThatOverlap.ToList();
    }
```

---

***Further explanation***

I know it's weird to match your Startdate with the end of your period and vice versa. But this makes sense. If we consider valid start dates, there can be two options:

- Those that started **in** the period you're looking for (`startPeriod` < `myDate.Start` < `endperiod`)
- Those that started **before** the period you're looking for (`myDate.Start` < `startPeriod` < `endperiod`)

If you look in the parentheses, you will see an unexpected (but undeniable) truth: it does not matter whether `myDate.Start` happened before or after `startPeriod`; since either *could be* correct.
However, in both cases, `myDate.Start` will **always** be smaller than `endperiod`. This is why we match `myDate.Start` to `endperiod`.

If `myDate.Start` is not smaller than `endPeriod`, **then it happened too late**.

The same logic holds true for considering `myDate.End` and `startperiod`. If you write it down, you'll see the same pattern.

**Note** I only elaborated on one of the two comparisons (since they work on the same principle), **but you must use both** if you want correct output. These cannot work separately, as both of them are incomplete evaluations (but together, they are complete)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `DateTime.Compare` method:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: How will that help? `<=` and `>=` are perfectly well defined for dates...